# Regular expression for validating name

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to validate an address input field on my form and it must be entered in the following format "City, Province, Country"

I am using the following regular expression to do this

```
^[^,]+,\s\w[^,]+,\s\w[^,]+$
```

When entering "New York, New York, United States" this would be valid. However, when I enter "N, N, United States" it does not work. It seems one letter words will not work. I need to allow users to only enter a single letter as well.

Not sure if the regular expression I have written is complicated and can be simplified

Comment: Perhaps `^\w+,\s*\w+,\s*\w+$` -- you have `\w` *and* `[^,]` in the second two sections.

Comment: just make `\s` as optional `^[^,]+,\s?\w[^,]+,\s?\w[^,]+$` or make it to repeat zero or mote times like `\s*`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check for dashes:

((\w)|(-)|(\s))+,\s*((\w)|(-)|(\s))+,\s*((\w)|(-)|(\s))+$